# Phonegap - Send array from mvc controller to Javascript using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, cordova, controller

I'm using phonegap and I'm trying to send an array encoded as json from a controller to view.

In my controller (server side):

```
$users = Model_Users::find(1);
$a=$users->to_array();
return json_encode($a);
```

In my view (into smartphone application using phonegap):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $.ajax({
        url: 'my/url...',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {

                },
                success: function(data) { 
                        alert(data); 
                }
        });  
});
```

This working fine, infact in the view I get this alert:

```
data = {"name":"Jhon","surname":"Larry","age":"25"}
```

This work because the result of the query is only one row.

Instead when I try to get more than one query result, example:

```
$users = Model_Users::find('all');
$a=array();
foreach ($users as $user){
    array_push($a,$user->to_array());
}
return json_encode($a);
```

In this case an empty response comes up, in fact I get this alert:

```
data = []
```

What is the problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please post the result of print_r($a) (and eventually even json_encode($a)) before returning the value on the server-side?

Comment: Result of print_r($a):

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => Brad [surname] => Pitt [age] => 40 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 4 [name] => Matt [surname] => Damon [age] => 38 ) )`

Result of json_encode($a):

`[{"id":"1","name":"Brad","surname":"Pitt","age":"40"},{"id":"4","name":"Matt","surname":"Damon","age":"38"}]`

Answer (score 0):

I will try to build an answer with some tips based on what we already know thanks to the comments.

First of all now we are sure that the JSON is valid (jsonlint.com for example).

So,now, we are completely sure that the problem resides on the PHP / server-side.
My solutions:

1. Pay attention to not echo/return something before the value you need;
2. Change `return` with `echo`;
3. Add an `exit;` statement after the echoed value to be sure that no other characters will be included in the server answer;
4. Not exactly needed, but you can even think to set the `header('Content-Type: application/json');`
5. Debug looking at the console and using `console.log` instead of `alert()` (there are a lot of threads explaining the difference

Hope this will help!

Comment: In the call of the model there is a damn "where" clause so my code is correct and the empty result was correct!!!!! Thanks Lorenzo!

Comment: I didn't understand because the resulting array was not empty in the PHP, we printed it, right? Anyway the important thing is that you solved :)